# Prediction value in sample tree made by H2O random forest

Tags: random-forest, h2o

Currently I am doing a random forest by H2O package and have plotted a sample tree for presentation purpose. The prediction value of each node is not quite the same as probability of positive class over the all instances of the node.

Just wondering to know how H2O calculate the prediction value. I need a formula to derive this prediction! I know that random forest goes over the average of the trees' prediction. But how is this prediction calculated at each node of each tree?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any way by node, I mean leaf node

Answer (score 0):

See algorithm 15.1 from the Elements of Statistical Learning:

- https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf

And then see the code for the implementation of the model training process in H2O-3:

- https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-algos/src/main/java/hex/tree/drf/DRF.java

Finally, the best way to understand how the actual generated model is used for producing scores is the genmodel MOJO implementation which you can find here (try using a java debugger to single-step through a call to score0()):

- https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-genmodel/src/main/java/hex/genmodel/algos/drf/DrfMojoModel.java

Comment: Thanks for your response but the algorithm is talking about the aggregation process which is not my question. I am looking for the prediction value which is a number between [0,1] interval and appears at the leaf node for just a sample tree.

Comment: in order to make in clear, I ran my h20 random forest by one tree to see if the prediction value in leaf nodes are basically the same as probabilities but they are not the same !\

Comment: a sample tree that I am talking about is plotted here  https://www.h2o.ai/blog/finally-you-can-plot-h2o-decision-trees-in-r/

Comment: I updated the answer above.  Try single-stepping score0() in genmodel.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I still not quite get my answer. I am simply need to explain what are these numbers representing . that is it. those are my manager and they don't need details. my Also is there any way to give me R version of code as I don't use python

Comment: I found that these numbers in the leaf nodes are  (1-threshholds) per each branch. Now the question is how can we retrieve this threshold given the information of the tree?

Comment: For binary classification problems, the threshold is the max-F1 statistic calculated during the model training phase.  But you can always grab the probability of the positive class and threshold it any way you want.

Comment: My question in not about the threshold. Just wondering to know how p0 and P1 are calculated as the result of h2o.predict() command; and also  how can I interpret them

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which returns the exact probability rate of train data set as the prediction value in the sample tree. you just need to set your code as follow:

`h2o.randomforest(sample_rate = 1, calibrate_model = TRUE, and calibration_frame = train )`